# Design pattern dilemma in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing a dilemma in design pattern for my app.

I currently have a header component which is completely different on resolutions greater than 992px and less. In my component i have two different `<section>` tags that i show/hide based on the resolution (using media queries). Now the problem is if i use content projection `<ng-content>` i cannot have same child components added in both (`<section>`) tags at once. For this reason i have to use `<ng-content>` with "select" parameter. However with that i have to then include each child component twice (one for each ng-content in my header).

Not to mention some of the child components injected also have completely different layout on resolutions greater than 992px and less.

I cant seem to find a best practise for this kinda design?

1) Should i make two header components (one for mobile and desktop)?

2) Should i keep using single header component but content project child component twice (one for mobile and one for desktop)?

Some code for perspective:

*app-header component template*

```
<section class="desktop-header">
    This is my desktop header which is different in design
    <ng-content select="[desktop]"></ng-content>
</section>

<section class="mobile-header">
    This is my mobile header which is different in design
    <ng-content select="[mobile]"></ng-content>
</section>
```

*app-header being used in my app:*

```
<app-header>
    <app-child desktop></app-child>
    <app-child mobile></app-child>
</app-header>
```

P.S: Please note that app-child can be different (design wise) on desktop and mobile too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desktop and mobile headers are so completely different in functionality, I don't see an issue with having 2 separate components. It's better to have 2 simpler components where your app can make a clear decision in one place to decide which component will display, than to have 1 convoluted component with a lot of logic and many conditionals to decide how it should display. It's easier to maintain 2 simple and clear components than it is to manage 1 very complex component. Start with 2 different ones, then if you feel they are converging or overlapping a lot you can merge them into one.

TLDR: 2 different, straight-forward components will be easier to maintain than 1 overly complex component

Comment: Thanks @Eeks33 - What about the content projected inside? Most of the time the component projected will also have a different layout. In that case i can have two different component for each layout. However maintaining some of the states between desktop and mobile then adds burden on the parent component.

Comment: Think of it this way, your application is a tree structure of components. If any 1 node gets too complex, you want to split that node, and then yes, the parent of those 2 nodes takes on a little bit of the burden. This is done so that the integration point of each node remains simple. If you find that at every level in your hierarchy you're fighting and maintaining logic about mobile vs desktop, then you can keep pushing the burden of knowing mobile vs desktop higher in the tree. Eventually, you'll be faced with the notion of mobile pages vs desktop pages, and finally mobile app vs web app.

Comment: Previous comment was too long, to finish it off - Ultimately a little repetition might be less costly than over complexity. Ask yourself which battle you want to fight and what will work better for your application's needs

Comment: Thanks @Eeks33 - I will try it this way then